# How to make multiple editable parts on homepage/other pages in Silverstripe CMS?

Tags: silverstripe

I am new to Silverstripe so am still learning the best way to achieve certain results.

I have the following website: https://i.stack.imgur.com/icaVJ.jpg - that I have converted into a silverstripe theme etc. I have setup the front page as a HomePage.ss.

Now I want to be able to edit most parts of the page from the CMS. I have followed this tutorial on this website: http://www.silverstripe.org/learn/lessons/working-with-data-relationships-has-many - and have created a region under the "Articles" heading in the pic which comes up as a tab on the CMS in the admin panel. https://i.stack.imgur.com/PFQiN.png

My question is, is the best way to make parts editable to make them regions like what the video has shown etc? E.g if I wanted to edit the section in the pic that has the picture of the big ring and the text next to it, am I best to make this another region? What about for things like headings etc?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

There are several possibilities to solve this problem:

1. either use several `$has_many` for each group if you have a fixed structure
2. if you need flexibile structure you can use one of the several 'block' modules like https://github.com/bummzack/page-blocks or https://github.com/NobrainerWeb/Silverstripe-Content-Blocks.

There are some more modules like this around, each have pros and cons, depending if you need reusable blocks, translatable blocks, want to save the relations with `Versioned` etc... @lerni made an [overview about those modules](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JvodD2L9K4b4hIrq1lTKb1Mpky5pgoOY0fElgKrrgq8/edit#gid=0).